# How find the postive $m,n$,such $a^n\equiv 1\pmod m$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all positive integer pairs $(m,n)$ with $m,n \ge 2$ such that for all $a\in\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$, $$a^n\equiv 1\pmod m$$

If $(a,m)=1$, Euler's Theorem tells us that 
$$a^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m.$$
So one family of solutions is $(n,m) = (\phi (m), m)$. Is it possible to describe all families?

Comment: I had to delete my original answer-apparently I'm a moron who doesn't even understand the question. I DID understand the question-and the critic didn't understand MY answer. I'm rewriting it so it's clearer.

Comment: Do you want "all pairs $\left(m, n\right)$ where $n$ is divisible by the Carmichael function of $m$" as an answer? Because I don't see any better answer. (But then again I might not understand the question, given that its wording is less than clear.)

Comment: I believe I have a solution  to the question,but after the last few misfires, I've gotten gun-shy. I'm going to check it over carefully several times with several sources before I post it.I hope someone doesn't beat me to it,but I'd rather let someone else get the answer then make a fool out of myself again.

Comment: Something is wrong in what you say about the family of solutions $(n,m)=(\phi(m),m)$.  Consider $m=4$ so that $n=\phi(4)=2$.  It's not true that $a^2\equiv1\pmod 4$ for all $a\in\{1,2\}$.  (Also, there's a switch from "$(m,n)"$ in the box to "$(n,m)$" in the family of solutions.)

Comment: Consider mod 8.  $\phi(8) = 4$ so $a^4 \equiv 1 \mod 8$ whenever $(a,8)=1$ - in fact $a^2 \equiv 1 \mod 8$.  The group structure of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ is tied to the prime factorization of the units $\phi(m)$, which depends on the prime factorization of $m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A proof based in the roots of $X^n-1$**

> **Answer**: The only pairs satisfying your statement are $(p,p-1)$ for primes $p$

Given a pair of integers $(m,n)$ such that $n>1$ suppose that for every $k\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$ we have:
$$k^n\equiv 1 \mod m\tag1$$
As noticed by Barry Cipra $n$ must be smaller than $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $m$ because $p^{n}\not\equiv 1\mod m$ hence $n<p$, And as consequence of $(1)$the roots of $x^n-1$ in $\Bbb Z_p$ are exactly $1,\cdots,n$.

Now let's prove that $n\geq p-1$, by contradiction, assume that $n<p-1$:

- If $n$ is even then $p-1$ is another root of $x^n-1$ in $\Bbb Z_p$ which is absurd.
- If $n$ is odd then $n+1=2a$ with $a,2\leq n$ hence $n+1$ is another root of the polynomial ($2^n\equiv 1\mod p $ and $a^n\equiv 1\mod p$ implies $(n+1)^n\equiv 1\mod n$) which is absurd.

As a conclusion $n=p-1$. Now given another prime $q$ which divides $m$, we can prove using the same method (as we did for $p$) that $n\geq q-1$ and because $n=p-1$ we have $p=q$.
If $m$ is divisible by $p^2$, we know that:
$$(p-1)^{p-1}\equiv -p(p-1)+1 \mod p^2 $$
which is absurd because $(p-1)^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod m\equiv 1\mod p^2$ hence $m=p$

Finally we proved that $n=p-1$ and $m=p$ is aprime

Comment: @san I updated my solution

Comment: Elaqqad: The best answer is a combination of our two answers, I think. May I use your answer to improve mine?

Comment: ok no problem, you can

Answer (score 1):

This is only a very partial answer, mostly in the form of a pair of obvious observations.

First of all, in order to have $a^n\equiv1$ mod $m$ for **all** $a\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, $n$ must be smaller than the smallest prime divisor of $m$, since you cannot have $p^n\equiv1$ mod $m$ if $p\mid m$.

Second, the one obvious family of solutions is $(m,n)=(p,p-1)$ for (odd) primes $p$.  This is just Fermat's Little Theorem.  It does not generalize to $(m,\phi(m))$, since $\phi(m)$ in general is greater than the smallest prime divisor of $m$.

I am inclined to think there are no other solutions, but I don't have a proof.  If anyone can think of one, or can produce a solution (or family there of solutions) with nonprime $m$'s, please post it as an answer!

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for something called the "order" of an element belonging to the set of integers modulo m. Now, this term comes from abstract algebra, as the order of an element in some group (don't worry about the axioms for being a group, just know that the set of residues mod m is a group) is the exponent $k$ such that $a^k = e$.

Now, $e$ denotes the identity element of a group under some operation. In our case, this is the identity element of the integers under multiplication. This is pretty clearly seen to be 1. Thus, the order of some element modulo m is the integer $k$ such that $$a^k \equiv 1 (\bmod m)$$ Now, as you probably know, a is restricted to being a member of the reduced residue set modulo m, as in, any integer such that $(a,m)=1$. Thus, for $a$, we have $\phi (m)$ choices for a. Now, the integer $a$ such that $$a^{\phi (m)} \equiv 1 (\bmod m)$$ is known as a primitive root in number theory, or, a generator of the cyclic group of reduced residues modulo m in abstract algebra. So, you have the primitive roots, and then you have the elements of order $k <\phi (m)$. An element cannot have an order greater than $\phi (m)$.

Something to note is that the order of an element must divide $\phi (m)$. This can easily be proven using the division algorithm for $\phi (m)$, rewriting is as $kq+r$, and showing that $r=0$.

Another important theorem asserts that for any $prime$ modulus, the amount of primitive roots mod m is $\phi (p-1)$, where $p$ is prime. This can help you narrow down the rest of the coprime elements. Also, for checking the order of elements, since you know that the order must divide your phi function, it is only necessary to check powers that are divisors of $\phi (n)$, which is significantly faster.

I won't prove them (unless you really want..), but there are two theorems that are pretty helpful for moduli of certain forms. Firstly, for any odd $a$, $$a^{\phi (2^{\alpha})/2} \equiv 1 (\bmod 2^{\alpha})$$

And then we also have a theorem asserting that a primitive root exists if and only if $m = 1, 2, 4, p^{\alpha}$ or $2p^{\alpha}$, where m is you modulus.

Now, I'm not sure exactly what you meant by families, but I can say that the order of any element modulo m will divide $\phi (m)$, so the families would be all elements that have an order of a divisor of $\phi (m)$.

Comment: ? This post contains no non trivial information...

Comment: I know, your question is trivial. What is the problem?

Comment: This is not my question. I have merely edited it to make it more clear. Also, even if $d| \phi(m)$, this does not guarantee that all $a \in \{1, 2, \cdots, d\}$ have order that is a divisor of $d$.